# react native webview the microphone stops working if the app moves to the background

Tags: react-native, background-process, microphone, react-native-webview

the app has the implementation of calls and when we move the app to the background
the microphone stops working on ios devices (on android works fine)
why it happens? and how to solve this problem?

"react-native": "0.63.2"
"react-native-webview": "^10.8.3"
[image]